# Displaying TIME in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, time

How can I display data type TIME in SQL as 09:00 or 09:00AM instead of 09:00:00.000000

For instance, I have a column `start_time` and its type is `TIME`

When I insert data in it, `INSERT INTO Time(start_time) VALUES('09:00:00')`

It displays it as: `09:00:00.0000000`

Comment: 09:00:00.0000000 is what stored in SQL server, ok. Is it your problem ? Or is this the value you getting when you read the data base, and you need the value as in inserted format ?

Comment: A database only stores data. How you format that data for the user is not up to the database, but up to the programming language you are using. Can you please edit the question to include a snippet where you query the database, and echo the time as you do in your application? Any other code is not necessary, unless it directly influences how the time is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format dates as per your requirement.

have a look at

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

or

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

sample

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SYSDATETIME(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SYSDATETIME(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]

..........

Comment: you have to use select convert (varchar , start_time, 114) as [HH:MI(24H)] from ......

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at the [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function in T-SQL. This will allow you to format date and time values (and another values) any way you want to. The link I provided is for SQL 2014. Format was added in version 2012. You have your question tagged as 2008, so I'm not sure this answer will apply to you. If not, take a look at Cast and/or Convert [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

By the way, you may not know this but how you enter a date/time value into SQL Server has no relationship to how it is displayed. And, generally, the displaying of date and time values is done in some UI tier of an app, and not at the SQL Sever level, even though T-SQL provides methods for formatting dates and times.